# how to return array id whose c value is maximum

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

how to return id whose `c` value is max. It should return id 1 because its `c` value is max

```
var array = [{"id":1,"c":5,"f":8},{"id":2,"c":3,"f":9},{"id":3,"c":4,"f":3}];
```

Comment: what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the objects by checking the object's property in a single loop.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, c: 5, f: 8 }, { id: 2, c: 3, f: 9 }, { id: 3, c: 4, f: 3 }],
    maxC = array.reduce((a, b) => a.c > b.c ? a : b);
    
console.log(maxC);
console.log(maxC.id);
```

For getting more objects with the same max value, you could use an array as result set.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, c: 5, f: 8 }, { id: 2, c: 3, f: 9 }, { id: 3, c: 4, f: 3 }, { id: 4, c: 5, f: 3 }],
    maxC = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r || o.c > r[0].c) {
            return [o];
        }
        if (o.c === r[0].c) {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, undefined);
    
console.log(maxC);
```

Comment: This is the most optimal solution among all. It uses only one loop and returns exactly what's needed.

Comment: thats great thanks nina
one more thing i want to ask can we get all the id's that are max
eg. var array = [{ id: 1, c: 5, f: 8 }, { id: 2, c: 3, f: 9 }, { id: 3, c: 5, f: 3 }]
it should get id 1 and id 3 bcoz both are max

Answer (score 0):

Sort base on `c` value, and select first index.

```js
var array = [{"id":1,"c":5,"f":8},{"id":2,"c":3,"f":9},{"id":3,"c":4,"f":3}],
    max = array.sort((a,b) => b.c > a.c)[0];

console.log( max );
```

Comment: @JasbirRana, you can get the id by `max.id`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```js
var array = [{"id":1,"c":5,"f":8},{"id":2,"c":3,"f":9},{"id":3,"c":3,"f":3}];

var obj = {};
array.forEach((item) => {
  obj = !obj.id ? item : (obj.c > item.c ? obj : item);
});

console.log(obj); // gives object
console.log(obj.id); // gives id
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the maximum value first.

```
var maxC = Math.max.apply(null, array.map( s => s.c ));
```

Now `find` the item with `maxC`

```
var idWithMaxC = array.find( s => s.c === maxC ).id
```

**Demo**

```js
var array = [{
  "id": 1,
  "c": 5,
  "f": 8
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "f": 9
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "c": 4,
  "f": 3
}];

var maxC = Math.max.apply(null, array.map(s => s.c));

var idWithMaxC = array.find(s => s.c === maxC).id

console.log(idWithMaxC);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want lambda functions, this should be quite descriptive

```
function getMaxId ( array ) {
    var max_index = 0;
    var max = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        if( array[ i ].c > max ) {
            max = array[ i ].c;
            max_index = i;
        }
    }

    return array[ max_index ].id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at lodash

```js
var array = [{"id":1,"c":5,"f":8},{"id":2,"c":3,"f":9},{"id":3,"c":4,"f":3}];

console.log(_.maxBy(array, 'c'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i dont want to use lodash.js

Comment: then look at any of the other answers @JasbirRana and next time look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

In such kind of problems JavaScript Array methods (map, filter, reduce) are really helpful.

```js
var array = [{"id":1,"c":5,"f":8},{"id":2,"c":3,"f":9},{"id":3,"c":4,"f":3}];

let max = Math.max.apply(null, array.map(el => el.c));
let ID = array.filter(el => el.c === 5)[0].id;

console.log(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.sort((a,b) => b.c > a.c)[0].id;` (extending the existing answer to meet the OP's requirement)

```js
var array = [{"id":1,"c":5,"f":8},{"id":2,"c":3,"f":9},{"id":3,"c":4,"f":3}],
    maxCId = array.sort((a,b) => b.c > a.c)[0].id;

console.log( maxCId );
```